# PEMDAS:How to solve this exercise?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

I have the following problem:
$$100*\left\{24+100*[1001-4*(25*6+25*4)]\right\}$$

I'm very frustrated that I can't solve exercises like this. I have read about PEMDAS and followed the steps but somehow I am making a mistake because the result I get is not correct.(looked at answers in the book).

Can someone provide the steps in order to solve correctly this problem?

Comment: Arturo + Zev: I think Morphism should be asked for his steps first, rather than us simply doing it for him in a matter of minutes.

Comment: @GEdgar: I would not say that I "did it for him"; I explained what steps he needs to take, but did not take them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do the innermost products, $25*6$ and $25*4$. Then add them. Then multiply the result by $4$. Then subtract this from $1001$. Then multiply the answer by $100$. Then add $24$. Then multiply the result of that by $100$.

Or:

1. You will need to multiply $100$ by the result of what is in curly brackets;

   - What is in curly brackets requires you to add $24$ to the result of multiplying $100$ by the answer you get from inside the square brackets;

     -What is inside the square brackets requires you to start with $1001$, and subtract the result of multiplying $4$ by the result of what you have inside the round parentheses.

     - To compute what is inside the round parentheses, you first do the products ($25$ times $6$ and $25$ times $4$), and add them.

Now "unfold" that to get the answer.

Comment: I totally got it now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\myemph}[1]{{\color{red}{\bf #1}}}$
$$100*\left\{24+100*[1001-4*(\myemph{25*6}+\myemph{25*4})]\right\}$$
$$100*\left\{24+100*[1001-4*(\myemph{150+100})]\right\}$$
$$100*\left\{24+100*[1001-\myemph{4*(250)}]\right\}$$
$$100*\left\{24+100*[\myemph{1001-1000}]\right\}$$
$$100*\left\{24+\myemph{100*[1]}\right\}$$
$$100*\left\{\myemph{24+100}\right\}$$
$$\myemph{100*\left\{124\right\}}$$
$$\fbox{12400}$$